# What's the recommended approach to resetting migration history using Django South?

Tags: django, django-south

I've accumulated quite a few migrations using South (0.7) and Django (1.1.2) which are starting to consume quite a bit of time in my unit tests. I would like to reset the baseline and start a fresh set of migrations. I've reviewed the [South documentation](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/index.html), done the usual Google/Stackoverflow searching (e.g. "django south (reset OR delete OR remove) migration history") and haven't found anything obvious.

One approach I've contemplated would involve "starting over" by "removing" South or "clearing" the history manually (e.g. clear the db table, remove migration files from the migrations director) and just re-run,

> ./manage.py schemamigration southtut --initial

So, if anyone has done this before and has some tips/suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sometimes you need to manually add `__init__.py` to `appname/migrations`

Comment: How do you reset the migrations in 1.7 (with the built-in migration)?

Comment: @Timo : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations could be an approach. You can also just remove your *migrations/* directories and re-issue `./manage.py makemigrations` but bad things will happen if you don't start from a fresh db...

Comment: I think `squashmigrations` is the right answer

Answer (score 121, accepted):

> EDIT - I'm putting a comment below at the top of this as it's important to read it before the > accepted answer that follows @andybak
>
> > @Dominique: Your advice regarding manage.py reset south is dangerous
> >     and may destroy the database if there are any third party apps using
> >     south in the project, as pointed out by @thnee below. Since your
> >     answer has so many upvotes I'd really appreciate it if you could edit
> >     it and add at least a warning about this, or (even better) change it
> >     to reflect @hobs approach (which is just as convenient, but doesn't
> >     affect other apps) - thanks! –  chrisv Mar 26 '13 at 9:09
>
> Accepted answer follows below:

First, [an answer by the South author](http://groups.google.com/group/south-users/browse_thread/thread/888413f195acd9c2/0ee513da38240e19):

> As long as you take care to do it on all deployments simultaneously, there shouldn't be any problem with this. Personally, I'd do:
>
> ```
>     rm -r appname/migrations/ 
>     ./manage.py reset south 
>     ./manage.py convert_to_south appname
> ```
>
> (Notice that the “`reset south`” part clears migration records for ALL apps, so make sure you either run the other two lines for all apps or delete selectively).
>
> The `convert_to_south` call at the end makes a new migration and fake-applies it (since your database already has the corresponding tables). There's no need to drop all the app tables during the process.

Here's what I'm doing on my dev + production server when I need to get rid of all these unneeded dev migrations:

1. Make sure we have the same DB schema on both sides
2. delete every migrations folder on both sides
3. run ./manage.py reset south (as the post says) on both sides = clears the south table *
4. run ./manage.py **convert_to_south** on both sides (faking 0001 migration)
5. then I can re-start to make migrations and push the migrations folders on my server

* except if you want to clean only one app among others, if so you'll need to edit your south_history table and delete only the entries about your app.

Comment: Just for the record, the South author's response was as follows: 

As long as you take care to do it on all deployments simultaneously, 
there shouldn't be any problem with this. Personally, I'd do:
rm -r appname/migrations/
./manage.py reset south
./manage.py convert_to_south appname

(Notice that the "reset south" part clears migration records for ALL 
apps, so make sure you either run the other two lines for all apps or 
delete selectivey).

Comment: Note also that if you drop the tables, then you need `manage.py schemamigration app name --initial` instead of convert_to_south.

Comment: As of Django 1.5, the "reset" management command is gone. Instead, you'll want to do something roughly like `south.models.MigrationHistory.objects.all().delete()`.

Comment: @Dominique: Your advice regarding `manage.py reset south` is **dangerous** and **may destroy the database** if there are any third party apps using south in the project, as pointed out by @thnee below. Since your answer has so many upvotes I'd really appreciate it if you could edit it and add at least a warning about this, or (even better) change it to reflect @hobs approach (which is just as convenient, but doesn't affect other apps) - thanks!

Comment: Why was this so highly upvoted? You should almost NEVER completely delete your south_migrationhistory table. That would completely screw up any dependent apps with migrations you don't want to touch. Hob's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @Cerin isn't why the comment said to "notice that the “reset south” part clears migration records for ALL apps, so make sure you either run the other two lines for all apps or delete selectively", or do you pose a different concern?

Comment: Along with @chrisv's comment, it should made clearer that `reset south` isn't just dangerous for third-party apps. _It's going to erase the migration history of all of your project's apps._ @hobs has a best solution per app.

Comment: When I tried "./manage.py reset south", I got Unknown command: 'reset'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Answer (score 187):

If you need to selectively (for just one app) reset migrations that are taking too long, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12823039/623735) worked for me.

```
rm <app-dir>/migrations/*
python manage.py schemamigration <app-name> --initial
python manage.py migrate <app-name> 0001 --fake  --delete-ghost-migrations
```

Don't forget to manually restore any [dependencies](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/Dependencies) on other apps by adding lines like `depends_on = (("<other_app_name>", "0001_initial"),("<yet_another_app_name>", "0001_initial"))` to your `<app-dir>/migrations/0001_initial.py` file, as the first attribute in your migration class just below `class Migration(SchemaMigration):`.

You can then `./manage.py migrate <app-name> --fake --delete-ghost-migrations` on other environments, per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12823039/623735). Of course if you fake the delete or fake the `migrate zero` you'll need to manually delete any left-over db tables with a migration like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15799023/623735).

A more nuclear option is to `./manage.py migrate --fake --delete-ghost-migrations` on the live deployment server followed by a [my]sqldump. Then pipe that dump into [my]sql on the environments where you need the migrated, fully-populated db. South sacrilege, I know, but worked for me.

Comment: What I really want is "take models.py as gospel, and make me a clean on from that point on".  Thus retaining the ability to set a deployment up from scratch, or work from an existing deployment.

Comment: That's what this does.

Comment: @hobs I was getting a `DependsOnUnknownMigration` while faking the new initial migration. Thanks to your comment, I could figure out that I should update the `depends_on` statement wherever it refers to this app. This is really the best answer here. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 54):

Thanks to the answers by Dominique Guardiola and hobs, it helped me solve a hard problem.
However there are a couple of issues with the solution, here is my take on it.

Using `manage.py reset south` is **not a good idea** if you have any **third party apps** that uses South, for example `django-cms` (basically everything uses South).

`reset south` will delete all migration history for all apps that you have installed.

Now consider that you upgrade to the latest version of `django-cms`, it will contain new migrations like `0009_do_something.py`. South will surely be confused when you try to run that migration without having `0001` through `0008` in the migration history.

It is much better/safer to selectively reset only the apps that **you are maintaining**.

---

First of all, make sure that your apps don't have any desync between migrations on disk, and migrations that have been executed on the database. Otherwise there will be headache.

#### 1. Delete migration history for my apps

```
sql> delete from south_migrationhistory where app_name = 'my_app';
```

#### 2. Delete migrations for my apps

```
$ rm -rf my_app/migrations/
```

#### 3. Create new initial migrations for my apps

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration --initial my_app
```

#### 4. Fake execute the initial migrations for my apps

This inserts the migrations into `south_migrationhistory` without touching actual tables:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --fake my_app
```

Step 3 and 4 is actually just a longer variant of `manage.py convert_to_south my_app`, but I prefer that extra control, in such delicate situation as modifying the production database.

Comment: I edited my answer to incorporate fixes for the problems you found (just guessing at them based on your answer), and tested it on a production database with millions of rows.

Comment: This is pretty much what we're doing. If you use --delete-ghost-migrations option at step 4, you can leave out step 1.

Comment: You should specify the app names explicitly in `./manage.py migrate --fake` if you don't want to fake migrate other apps that have migrations pending.

Comment: @wadim Hence step 0: "make sure that you have no desync between migrations on disk, and migrations that have been executed on the database".

Comment: @thnee Right. It's probably worth mentioning that you're refering to all installed apps in step 0. Do you know of an easy way to perform step 0 though?

Comment: @thnee could you clarify the 'delete from', specifying the tool used?

Comment: @Bryce 'delete from' is raw SQL executed in the database shell.

Comment: What about datamigrations?

Answer (score 7):

Like thnee (see her answer), we're using a gentler approach to the South author's (Andrew Godwin) suggestion quoted elsewhere here, and we're separating what we do with the code base from what we do to the database, during deployment, because we need the deployments to be repeatable:

What we do in the code:

```
# Remove all the migrations from the app
$ rm -fR appname/migrations
# Make the first migration (don't touch the database)
$ ./manage.py schemamigration appname --initial
```

What we do to the database once that code is deployed

```
# Fake the migration history, wiping out the rest
$ ./manage.py migrate appname --fake --delete-ghost-migrations
```

Comment: I think I just did the same thing, but manually deleting database entries, rather than using --delete_ghoist-migrations. Your way is a bit nicer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just working on the dev machine, I wrote a management command that does pretty much what Dominique suggested.

http://balzerg.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/django-app-reset-with-south.html

In contrast of the south author suggestion, this will NOT HARM other installed apps using south.

Comment: And if, unlike the author, you want to *keep* existing migrations (i.e. you want to reset the app as well as migration history, but keep the actual migrations), then you can try this: http://goo.gl/0ZnWm

Answer (score 1):

Following is only if you want to reset all apps. Please backup your all databases prior to that work. Also note down your [depends_on](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html) in initial files if there are any.

For once:

```
(1) find . -type d -name migrations -exec git rm -rf '{}' \;
(2) find . -type d -name migrations -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
(3) ./manage.py schemamigration <APP_NAME> --initial
(4) [GIT COMMIT]
```

Test bootstrapping your project before push. Then, for each local/remote machine, apply following:

```
(5) [GIT PULL]
(6) ./manage.py reset south
(7) ./manage.py migrate --fake
```

Do initial (3) for **each app** you want to re-involve. Note that, reset (6) will delete only migration history, therefore not harmful to libraries. Fake migrations (7) will put back migration history of any 3rd party apps installed.

Answer (score 0):

delete necessary file from app folder

instance path

```
 cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wiki/south_migrations
```

wiki -is my app