# Django and South: using south makes syncdb show myapp as 'not synced (use migrations)'

Tags: django, django-south

When I run ./manage.py syncdb it says not synced (use migrations).  However, when I run

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
Nothing seems to have changed
$ ./manage.py migrate
blah blah, nothing to migrate
```

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout), I tried resetting south to fix the problem.  Here's what I did:

```
$ rm -r appname/migrations/ 
$ ./manage.py reset south
$ ./manage.py syncdb
    (at this point it shows all apps as synced)
$ ./manage.py convert_to_south myapp
blah blah, App 'blog' converted.
$ ./manage.py syncdb
    (at this point it shows myapp as not synced)
```

Running schemamigration > migrate has the same effect as before (nothing, still not registering as synced).
On the plus side, the app still seems to work fine, I'm just worried this could cause problems down the road.  Any idea what's going on and how I can fix it?  Is this even really a problem?  I'm using SQLite3 and Django 1.4.2 if that helps.

Comment: Easiet way to test: delete your local db. Start off fresh. What does `./manage.py syncdb --migrate` say?

Comment: It says that everything is synced, except for myapp which is migrated.  I think my answer below is correct.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The command in my previous comment should both sync the db for non-managed apps, and migrate for managed apps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might not be a problem, after all.  I just found [this bit](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#syncdb) in the South docs which seems to indicate that South takes over that functionality.  South "makes syncdb only work on a subset of the apps - those without migrations."  ie it's okay for syncdb to show myapp as not synced because south is handling it separately.

I hang my south-noob head in shame.