# Re-init migrations in South with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration, django-south

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the recommended approach to resetting migration history using Django South?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout)

I have a fairly old Django application running that's been in the hands of several developers along the way. Some developers have embraced South, while others have wanted to do all migrations manually, not using South.

This has led to some (rather, a lot) of our Apps have rather corrupt migrations, since some of them might rely on data that once existed, but doesn't anymore.

This is an issue in a lot of cases, for example whenever we wish to set up a new blank database from scratch; we always run into a lot of manually work where we end up having to fake migrations until we get past the issues.

So the question becomes: how do we most effectively re-init all of our migrations so that we start from scratch, migration-wise - and thus ensures everything is fine (the current developers all use South, so no issues in that regard anymore)?

Would the following be enough:

- Delete all migration folders and files within them
- Delete the migration tables in our PostgreSQL database
- Make the initial migration

Would this work, given that we delete the migrations tables in both the development and production database?