# South migrations are messed up

Tags: django, django-south

South Migrations are messed up. What can I do to reset migrations for my django app without breaking anything?

Comment: You might want to try looking at this other [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout).

Comment: what did you do to break it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the directory for the app whose migration is "messed up", there should be a sub-directory called "migrations." If you delete the files in that directory (all, or just the one that caused the problem) you can re-run manage.py schemamigration yourapp.