# OneToOne Fields on users causing some ID problems

Tags: django, django-south

I have a bit of a problem using django-registration and signals.
The basic setup is that I have a django 1.4.3 setup, with django-south and django-registration (and the db is SQLite for what it's worth).

*EDIT: I changed the question a bit because the effect is the same in a shell, so the registration is not in cause (edits are in italic).*

I have a one of my model that is related to the User model in the following way:

```
class MyUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneFiled(User)
    #additional fields
```

I initialized the base using south.
When I do a little `sqlall` to check the sql that should be in it, I can clearly see:

```
CREATE TABLE "myApp_myuserprofile" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    #other fields
)
```

After that, I wanted to initialize the data if the user activated its account.
So in models.py I put

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from registration.signals import user_activated
#Models....
@receiver(user_activated)
def createMyProfile(sender, **kwargs):
    currentUser = kwargs['user']
    profile = Profile(user = currentUser, #other fields default value)
    profile.save()
    #And now the reverse relation:
    currentUser.myuserprofile = profile
    currentUser.save()
```

While I am in there, everything seems alright, if I print the ids (both for the user and the profile), and if I travel back and forth between the 2, I see something that seems correct.

*If I disable this part of the code and do the same kind of initialization using the shell, I get the same result.*

But after that, everyhting is wrong.
If I open a shell and import the relevant matters, I have the following for every X value

```
MyUserProfile.objects.get(pk=X) 
#DoesNotExist Exception
User.objects.get(pk=X).myuserprofile.pk
1
MyUserProfile.objects.all()[X].pk
1
```

Seems a bit weird no?

And now if I go to the sql shell

```
select id from myApp_myuserprofile;
1
1
1
1
...
```

So I have a primary column which is filled with the same value all over the place. Which is well... embarrassing to say the least (and does lead to problem, because everyone has a profile with the same Id).

Any idea to what could be the cause of the problem and how I could solve it?

P.S: Note that the foreign key from the related relation are correct and their uniqueness is preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looks like the problem was indeed coming from the use of SQLite and South.

The [doc](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/databaseapi.html#database-specific-issues) states that:

> SQLite doesn’t natively support much schema altering at all, but South has workarounds to allow deletion/altering of columns. Unique indexes are still unsupported, however; South will silently ignore any such commands.

Which was (I think) the case, as I hadn't created this relation from the start but with a latter migration. I just reseted the base and migrations and voilà.

See [What's the recommended approach to resetting migration history using Django South?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout) for the migrations and a simple `./manage.py reset myApp` for the base reset.