# remove a migration from south migration history

Tags: django, django-south, rollback

I have an app named 'robots' and used 0.9 version of it

I later find out 0.9 has a feature I don't want and downgraded to 0.8

After sometime, I try to do south migrate on my project and meet an error 
`south.exceptions.NoMigrations: Application '<module 'robots' from '/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/codingqna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robots/__init__.pyc'>' has no migrations.`

I guess 0.9 had migrations file but 0.8 doesn't, and south is complaining about it.

How do I remove this from south's history like it never existed? (like I used 0.8 from the beginning without the migrations files)

Or any other way I can use here?

Comment: there are several approaches for resseting your migration history. You can find them here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout

Comment: I definately don't want to reset and start from fresh.. that will wipe out so many data I can't recover in production. I wonder deleting from south_migrationhistory table is doable in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from south_migrationhistory where app_name='robots';
```

south_migrationhistory table just keeps track of what migrations have been applied and what are yet to be applied. Since 0.8 of robots doesn't have any migration files any entries for it from table south_migrationhistory can be removed and it won't affect anything else.

Comment: precise answer I was looking for!