# Django, reset South migrations

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

Recently, I moved from Linux Mint to Ubuntu, uploaded my project's code to Github, downloaded it again and tried to continue developing. But I have a problem with South:

I tried migrating the apps(many apps) normally:

manage.py schemamigration apps --auto,

But I got:

"You cannot use --auto on an app with no migrations. Try --initial."

Then I tried '--initial',

But when I migrated the apps '$ ./manage.py migrate apps', I got:

"These migrations are in the database but not on the disk:

...(all the migrations I had, not sure how they ended up there)

I'm not trusting myself; either fix this yourself by fiddling
  with the south_migrationhistory table, or pass --delete-ghost-migrations
  to South to have it delete ALL of these records (this may not be good)."

I don't care about keeping the migrations so I tried python manage.py --delete-ghost-migrations, but I got "Unknown command".

Then I tried reseting migrations the way [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout) post recommends, so I did:

$ python manage.py reset south

But I got "Unknown command" again.

¿How can I fix this so I can keep working on my project? Sorry if it is something obvious.

*When I was working on Linux Mint I used Mysql, now on Ubuntu I intalled Postgre. This probably doesn't have anything to do with the error cause I think I got it right and configured it correctly with my django project. But maybe you should know it if the solution needs some database manipulation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command to clear the database:

```
./manage.py sqlclear south | ./manage.py dbshell
```

then make sure to remove the migrations directory in the app to fully reset south:

```
rm [app_name]/migrations
```

Comment: This worked but due to problems with Windows/sqlite3/virtualenv/python I had to manually download sqlite-shell-win32 and place the exe in my project directory. Thanks!
https://sqlite.org/download.html