# Django south not applying database migration

Tags: python, django, django-south

I made some changes to my model.py file... I added another field (fds_name):

```
from django.db import models

class funds(models.Model):
    fds_symbol  = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    fds_name  = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I ran the South schema migration command, and it detected the change and made a migration:

```
/var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/python3 manage.py schemamigration corefinance --auto
tail corefinance/migrations/0002_auto__add_funds.py
        models = {
            'corefinance.funds': {
                'Meta': {'object_name': 'funds'},
                'fds_name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128'}),
                'fds_symbol': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '5'}),
                'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'})
            }
        }

        complete_apps = ['corefinance']
```

However, when I run the migration, it says there's nothing to migrate, and I can see that the database is still missing the new field.

```
/var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/python3 manage.py migrate corefinance
Running migrations for corefinance:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for corefinance.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because between the `--initial` migration and the next schemamigration you have to persist the actual migration to the db issuing the command `python manage.py migrate corefinance`.

After doing that first migration then you may add another field, do and schemamigration `--auto` and commit it to the db again by doing `python manage.py migrate corefinance`

Comment: I did see your other answer, but I'm pretty sure that I did run that command: /var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/python3 manage.py migrate corefinance

Comment: ok remove the migration folder in your corefinance and also remove the last created row(0002_auto__add_funds) from the south table and again run the initial migration and then migrate it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I had to actually drop the funds table before the migration would run. What happens in the future when I've got important data in the funds table?

Comment: You should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit more finnicky than dhana's answer, but it works. You can manually change the database schema through your database admin interface, then run [a fake migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html/#options). By doing this, Django will think the schemamigration has been applied, and all necessary database changes will have already been made.