# Django 1.8 TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am learning to use Django and I get an error when I do the "migrate". I was using DateTimeField with error:

```
Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, sessions, auth, principal Running migrations:   Applying principal.0002_auto_20140910_1459.../Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1350: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Producto.tiempo_registro received a naive datetime (2014-09-10 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.   RuntimeWarning)

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 336, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 193, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 37, in database_forwards
    field,   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 160, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 74, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 189, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1774, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.related_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 632, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 913, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.dev20140910084412-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 921, in get_prep_value
    return int(value) TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

But if I comment the line and do "migrate" I get the same error.

Paste the models.py:

```
#encoding:utf-8
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Producto(models.Model):
 nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 #precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, help_text='Con solo dos decimales')
 #imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='productos', verbose_name='Imagen producto', null=True)
 #fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField('date published')
 #usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
 def __str__(self):
   return self.nombre
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us entire traceback.

Comment: This error doesn't reflect the current state of your models, but the state of your models when the migration was originally created (ie. when the `makemigrations` command was originally run). Since you are just learning and the migration was never applied you should probably just delete the offending migration file and create a new migration. Also, I think it would be wiser to learn using a stable version of Django.

Comment: I found the solution in this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout

Comment: I recommend you use Django 1.7 instead, it's only just been released. Django 1.8 is under development.